# How to remove another user data in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an app which saves the data in two different users (A and B) database. I just need a code for user A to delete the data of user B database. I'm using Firebase as database.

I have a code, but this is not working:

```
        DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Volunteer");
    driverRef.orderByKey().equalTo(userId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String key = postsnapshot.getKey();
                DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Volunteer").child(key).child("requests").child("customerRideId");
                driverRef.removeValue();


            }
        }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: It looks like you'll need to know the `userId` of user B to be able to delete their geo-location data. With that it's as simple as `geoFire.removeLocation(userIdOfUserB)`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for replying,but how can i find user id of B

Comment: To delete another user's individual data, you must know who that user is. If you're just trying to delete all users: `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("requests"). removeValue()`

Comment: Yes @FrankvanPuffelen but how can i find id of another user.

Answer (score 2):

You need to retrieve the `userid` of the other person from the database, so user A will be able to delete data of user B.

If you have this:

```
User
 useruidA
     name: userA
     email: userA@gmail.com
 useruidB
     name: userB
     email: userB@gmail.com
```

when you are retrieving the name of userB, then also retrieve the his id, to be able to delete it.

Alternatively you can do this:

```
 DatabaseReference data = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
data.orderByChild("name").equalTo(userB).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
     @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        data.getRef().removeValue();

              }

        }
```

that way, you do not need his `id` only the name.